# Combining results of mongoDB queries in a Javascript Map

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, dictionary

I run two queries to combine the results in a map (faster than running a bigger, combined query).

I build the dictionary with the `_id` field and set the whole object as the value.

```
let sessions = await getListSessions(minDate, maxDate);
if (config.combineResults) {
    const altSessions = await getAltListSessions(minDate, maxDate);
    const sessionMap = new Map();
    sessions.forEach((element) => {
        sessionMap.set(element._id, element);
    });
    sessions = [];
    altSessions.forEach((altSession) => {
        if (sessionMap.has(altSession._id)) {
            const session = sessionMap.get(altSession._id);
            session.metrics = altSession.metrics;
            sessions.push(session);
        }
    });
}
return sessions;
```

Oddly enough, none of the keys are found. I debugged each line, the map gets created, the keys are set and they are identical if I output them to the log, but Javascript doesn't return any matches on `has` or `get`. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, even if the `_id`'s in MongoDB return as strings, applying `toString()` on them fixes the issue:

```
sessions.forEach((element) => {
    sessionMap.set(element._id.toString(), element);
});
//...
if (sessionMap.has(altSession._id.toString())) {
        const session = sessionMap.get(altSession._id.toString());
```

A better answer would be welcome though.